# Can creative element owners claim copyright on Machine Learning models or its output?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

In [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/19981/286) if the ML model is trained using [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org) (**C** - ***software***) and [TacoTron](https://google.github.io/tacotron/publications/tacotron/index.html) or [TacoTron 2](https://google.github.io/tacotron/publications/tacotron2/index.html) (**B** - ***algorithm***), which both are free for commercial use, can the owner of that creative work (**A**) claim copyrights on the model and its output?

***Aside:*** *I'm of the opinion that if voice actors aren't subjects to copyright claims when they do voice imitations (take Donald Duck's voice for instance), then IA voices shouldn't either.*

---

**Update:** My purpose for training a ML model with some voice data set is to have some text input and  make the output indistinguishable of a human voice recording. My intention is not to impersonate whoever those recordings belong to, nor hint somehow that it could be the case.

In fact, down the road I'm sure it will be a way to tweak some parameters to make the voice sound completely different of the one used to train the model.

Comment: Why would the license of B and C influence the copyright of A?!

Comment: @MSalters I'm not suggesting that, I just wanted to make clear that there is no other party involved.

Comment: Well, there _are_ other parties. Components B and C have authors, and those authors have copyright on their parts - just like in the linked question. This really appears to be a duplicate of the original question.

Comment: @MSalters TensorFlow has the [Apache License 2.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/LICENSE) and there are already some [implementations](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=tacotron&type=) of the Tacotron algorithm with a similar permissive licenses (also [Apache-2.0](https://github.com/Kyubyong/tacotron/blob/master/LICENSE) and [MIT](https://github.com/keithito/tacotron/blob/master/LICENSE)).

Comment: I know, I work for an AI company. My point is that legally, the Tensorflow license wouldn't matter much. If anything, what would matter is the Tensorflow copyright owner (Google, Inc). But even that doesn't affect the owner "A".

Comment: @MSalters as a side note, both the algorithm and its implementations are worthless without the input data to build the model, maybe that's why they are giving them away for free. What I can't tell for sure is whether the model and the output are also subject to the same copyright as the input data. It's as if voice actors would have to pay royalties when they do imitations of some voices like for instance Donald Duck's.

Comment: "I'm of the opinion that if voice actors aren't subjects to copyright claims when they do voice imitations (take Donald Duck's voice for instance)" -- this should be a separate question. Imitating a copyrighted character's voice may or may not be infringing. If it is infringing, it may or may not be pursued by the copyright owners.

Comment: @Brandin I've added a clarification, thanks for pointing that out.